# Delphi drag and drop files from Windows explorer to TListView does not work

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition. I'm trying to drag and drop files from a Windows folder onto my application but the Windows message handler is not called when I drag and drop a file on the form.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  protected
    procedure WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
    ShellApi;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin

    // Disable drag accept files
    DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, true);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

    // Enable drag accept files
    DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, true);

end;

procedure TForm1.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
begin

    // Show a message
    ShowMessage('File dropped');

    // Set the message result
    Msg.Result := 0;

    inherited;

end;

end.
```

Like I said, when I drag and drop a file on the form, I can see that the file is accepted when dragged onto the form but when I drop the file, the `WMDropFiles` procedure is not called.

I also tried enabling the `DragAcceptFiles` in the `CreateWnd` procedure. But it still does not work.

```
...
public
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;

...

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin

  inherited;
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, True);

end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWnd;
begin

  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, False);
  inherited;

end;
```

I even tried running the Delpi IDE as Administrator.
Could it be a limitation of the Community Edition or am I missing something?

### Addendum

I've now added a button to send a message `WM_DROPFILES`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SendMessage(Self.Handle, WM_DROPFILES, Integer(self), 0);
end;
```

When I click the button, the `WMDropFiles` procedure is called. So then it works.

Comment: FYI, the *preferred* way to accept dropped data, including files, is to implement the [`IDropTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget) interface. `WM_DROPFILES` is a legacy deprecated API. See [Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/dragdrop). Anders Melander has an excellent [Drag&Drop suite for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop) which implements `IDropTarget` for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi Remy, long time since I've last seen you!! Think it was Indy Sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, very interesting. I found this article:

[How to Enable Drag and Drop for an Elevated MFC Application on Vista/Windows 7](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/)

So I added the following to my form create procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin


    // Enable drag accept files
    DragAcceptFiles(Form1.Handle, true);

    ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);
    ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
    ChangeWindowMessageFilter ($0049, MSGFLT_ADD);

end;
```

And now it is working!

Answer (score -1):

I changed the topic to include text "TListView" because I actually want to drop files on a TListView. Since I've solved the problem with dropping files on a form, I still had an issue with dropping files on a TListView.

So to drop the files on a TListView, you have to change the Handle to the listview's handle:

```
// Enable drag accept files
DragAcceptFiles(MyListview.Handle, true);
```

and

```
// Disable drag accept files
DragAcceptFiles(MyListview.Handle, false);
```

But that alone is not enough. You then need a `Application` events handler to catch the messages and handle them accordingly. So I just added a `TApplicationEvents` component to the form and added the following to the `OnMessage` event:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin

    // If it is a drop files message and it is for the listview
    if ((Msg.message = WM_DROPFILES)and (Msg.hwnd = MyListView.Handle)) then
    begin

        // Handle your dropped data here

    end;

end;
```

Comment: Rather than using `TApplicationEvents`, I would subclass the `TListView` itself instead, not the application message queue. You can provide a new message handler directly to the `TListView.WindowProc` property, or you can derive from `TListView` and override its virtual `WndProc()` method (you could then override its virtual `(Create|Destroy)WindowHandle()` methods to call `DragAcceptFiles()`), or you can use the Win32 `SetWindowsLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or better `SetWindowsSubclass()` API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I know I can direct the messages to the ListView WndProc